# Wordpress: how to overwrite specific update notice

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, custom-post-type

So I've made it so that if u delete a member from my member custom post type that it doesn't go to trash and just permanently deletes it.
the problem is I still get this message shown below:

[image]

how can I overrule the message in my functions.php

I know I can just `/wp-admin/edit.php` I can just comment out:

```
echo '<div id="message" class="updated notice is-dismissible"><p>' . join( ' ', $messages ) . '</p></div>';
```

but of course, this doesn't work permanently and breaks whenever u update.

So how do I get rid of the 1 post moved to the trash message?

**UPDATE**

the code to delete users from post type + Wordpress users I use is as follows:

```
add_action('trashed_post', 'on_delete_members');
function on_delete_members()
{
    $post = get_post();
    if ($post->post_type === 'members' ) {
        $email_address = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'email', true);
        $user = get_user_by('email', $email_address);

        $id = $user->ID;

        wp_delete_user($id);

        wp_delete_post($post->ID, true);
    }
}
```

Comment: No matter how much you update this, when you update your wordpress, chances are most files and the files we will edit will get replaced/overwritten. so unless there is a value in the database that allows you to change, I think you will almost always after an update have to do this.

Comment: but there must be a way to overrule it or something inside functions.php
or like change the message instead of deleting it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never change WordPress core files. Ever!

You should use [admin_notices](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_notices/) hook to customize those messages in your custom post type:

```
<?php
function so60507901_sample_admin_notice__success() {
    ?>
    <div class="notice notice-success is-dismissible">
        <p><?php _e( 'Done!', 'sample-text-domain' ); ?></p>
    </div>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'admin_notices', 'so60507901_sample_admin_notice__success' );
?>
```

Once your code is not complete, I can't create a full working example. So you need to adjust it to your needs.

Comment: this doesn't really answer my question. this is just how to add an admin notice to the custom post type screen. and it doesn't really overrule the message I talked about

Comment: Hiding the message with CSS would be a solution?

Comment: yeah but then even if I hide it, if I would delete a member from the custom post type it would still show the original message: post moved to trash. 
my question was more on how to get rid of that message.

Answer (score 0):

The filter you need to use is `bulk_post_updated_messages` which allows you to filter all the messages pertaining to the bulk operations. The documentation about the filter is [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/bulk_post_updated_messages/).

The `$bulk_messages` parameter passed to the callback function contains all the messages used by bulk operations as an associative, two-dimensional array where the first-level index is the post type (e.g. `post` or `page`) and the second-level indexes are: `updated`, `locked`, `deleted`, `trashed` and `untrashed`.

When a custom post type doesn't define its own messages, then the ones from the `post` post type are used.

If you do not want to create your own messages for your custom post type, what you could do is add the following callback function:

```php
add_filter( 'bulk_post_updated_messages', 'my_bulk_post_messages_filter' );

function my_bulk_post_messages_filter( $bulk_messages ) {
    global $post_type;

    if ( 'my_custom_post_type' === $post_type ) {
        $bulk_messages['post']['trashed'] = $bulk_messages['post']['deleted'];
    }

    return $bulk_messages;
}
```

The callback copies the same message defined for permanently deleted posts to the trashed posts. Since you are forcing those posts to be permanently deleted, the final result would be printing the correct message for your specific case.

Of course, you could also define your own complete set of messages, specific to your custom post type. An example of such a callback can be found [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/bulk_post_updated_messages/#comment-4682).

An intermediate solution would be using the default messages for certain operations while customizing only the ones you want to change. A possible callback in that scenario would be:

```php
add_filter( 'bulk_post_updated_messages', 'my_bulk_post_messages_filter', 10, 2 );

function my_bulk_post_messages_filter( $bulk_messages, $bulk_counts ) {
    global $post_type;

    if ( 'my_custom_post_type' === $post_type ) {
        $bulk_messages['my_custom_post_type'] = $bulk_messages['post'];
        $bulk_messages['my_custom_post_type']['trashed'] = _n( '%s member permanently deleted.', '%s members permanently deleted.', $bulk_counts['trashed'] );
    }

    return $bulk_messages;
}
```